# Inconsistent Ansible/YAML format for Lists?

Tags: ansible, yaml

I need some help understanding why, when I create a YAML file for an Ansible playbook that exactly mirrors what is specified in the module documentation, lists and list_items aren't being parsed correctly when the YAML is read by Python.

My understanding is that when reading through documentation about Ansible modules on Github, items are displayed within columns to denote their relationship relative to items above-and-below them. Further, if an item is defined as "**list / elements=dictionary**" then that means the following:

1. Typing of the item must be finished by adding a colon-and-space (this
   defines "dictionary" items)
2. The next/subsequent line must begin at
   the same indentation level (or greater) and start with a
   hyphen-and-space (this denotes a "list" item)
3. The order of items in a list must be followed exactly.
4. Subsequent list items must be at the same level of indentation as the first item in the list
5. If any given sub-item in the list is ITSELF another "**list / elements=dictionary**" item repeat
   step-2 again.

(EXAMPLE: Taken from the **[cisco.ios.ios_ospfv2](https://github.com/ansible-collections/cisco.ios/blob/main/docs/cisco.ios.ios_ospfv2_module.rst)** module)
So if the main item of "**processes**" is a "**list / elements=dictionary**" composed of the following:

1. areas (also a "list / elements=dictionary")
2. network (also a "list /
   elements=dictionary")
3. process_id (integer)

Then the correct YAML syntax for the above would be:

```
processes: 
- areas: 
  - area_id: 0 ##dictionary_item
  - authentication: ##dictionary_item
      message_digest: true ##boolean
- network: 
  - address: '10.1.1.0' ##string
  - area: '0' ##string
  - wildcard_bits: 0.0.0.255. ##integer
- process_id: 1
```

However, even though I don't get any YAML errors when I start my Playbook, I do get a bunch of obscure Python tracebacks.  But if I change my code to THIS (see below) it works!

```
processes: 
- process_id: 1
  areas: 
  - area_id: '0'
    authentication: 
      message_digest: true
  network: 
    address: 0.0.0.0
    area: 0
    wildcard_bits: 255.255.255.255
```

My questions:

1. If the order of list_items is important, why did my file NOT work when I followed the order specified in the module documentation...but it DOES work when that order is ignored ("process_id" should NOT be first according to the docs for this module)?
2. I understand that not EVERY list_item needs to be preceded with a hyphen-space.  But I DID think that the FIRST list_item required this.  So why (in my first example) does my playbook fail when I denote the sub-items under "network" with hyphens...but when I remove ALL of the hyphens from this list, it DOES work? However it DOES require a hyphen for the first list_item under "areas"??

[Python Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gatwv.png)

(sorry for the long post...I didn't know to condense it any further than this)

Comment: What data structure are you familiar with? What is your main coding language? Would that help if we translate that in the language your are "used to"?

Comment: Most people who "implement" yaml as the configuration format have no idea what it truly is that they are implementing. It's a data format that's so fundamentally broken that its popularity defies my understanding. Protip to anyone thinking that yaml is a good idea: do some research, look into corner cases, see what you're really getting your users into :/ I've been using Ansible way too much at one point, and while what you describe may not necessarily be a bug, it kills the usability of the thing if you want to do anything that's not trivial and covered in tutorials. Par for the course here.

Comment: @UnslanderMonica TBH, I do partially get the aversion of YAML, you're not the first person I see raising this. This said, it is a little bit like any language using `{}` to indicate blocks versus Python using indentation to indicate blocks. So I do totally get people favouring JSON over YAML, but that's like most of the things: a matter of tastes. There are quirks in YAML though, but this question is not one of those cases.

Answer (score 0):

Here is for a general explanation of this YAML:

```yaml
processes: 
- process_id: 1
  areas: 
  - area_id: '0'
    authentication: 
      message_digest: true
  network: 
    address: 0.0.0.0
    area: 0
    wildcard_bits: 255.255.255.255
```

- `processes`: you may have 1 to N process, so it is a list, and in this case, a list of dictionary.
  You should expect something like:

  ```yaml
  processes:
    - foo: bar
      baz: qux
    - foo: some
      baz: thing
  ```
- `process_id`: is an int, you should expect:

  ```yaml
  processes:
    - foo: bar
      baz: qux
      # since you are in a dictionary, 
      # process_id can be anywhere in the dictionary, 
      # as the first, last, or anywhere in between key 
      process_id: 1 
    - foo: some
      baz: thing
      # since you are in a dictionary, 
      # process_id can be anywhere in the dictionary, 
      # as the first, last, or anywhere in between key 
      process_id: 2
  ```

  So this is the exact same YAML

  ```yaml
  processes:
    - process_id: 1
      # since you are in a dictionary, 
      # process_id can be anywhere in the dictionary, 
      # as the first, last, or anywhere in between key  
      foo: bar
      baz: qux
    - process_id: 2
      # since you are in a dictionary, 
      # process_id can be anywhere in the dictionary, 
      # as the first, last, or anywhere in between key 
      foo: some
      baz: thing
  ```
- `areas`: is a list of 1 to N area, under the key `areas` of a dictionary, nested in a list, of key `processes`

  ```yaml
  processes:
    - process_id: 1
      areas:
        - area_id: '0'
          authentication: 
            message_digest: true
        - area_id: '1'
          authentication: 
            message_digest: true
    - process_id: 2
      areas:
        - area_id: '0'
          authentication: 
            message_digest: true
  ```
- `network`: is a dictionary in a dictionary

  ```yaml
  processes:
    - process_id: 1
      areas:
        - area_id: '0'
          authentication: 
            message_digest: true
        - area_id: '1'
          authentication: 
            message_digest: true
    - process_id: 2
      areas:
        - area_id: '0'
          authentication: 
            message_digest: true 
      network: 
        address: 0.0.0.0
        area: 0
        wildcard_bits: 255.255.255.255
  ```

So in general, pay attention to how Ansible is also giving you hints here: `areas` is pluralised for a good reason: because it is a list of area. Same goes for `processes`. While `network` is a singular, so, as expected it will be a dictionary and not a list.

---

> list / elements=dictionary

Means that processes must be a list where each element is a dictionary.

In YAML this is a dictionary:

```yaml
foo:
  some: bar
  property: bar
  of: bar
  the: bar
  dictionary: bar
  of: bar
  key: bar
  foo: bar
```

And this is a list:

```yaml
fruits:
  - banana
  - apple
  - pear
  - peach
```

Then a list of dictionary would be:

```yaml
- the:
    red: fox
    jump: over
- the:
    lazy: dog
```

Mind that, because this is a list, then the same key can be reproduced in the different elements of the list but cannot be seen twice in the same dictionary.

---

So to answer your second question, you are correct that in a dictionary the order of keys do not matter:

```yaml
the:
  red: fox
  jump: over
```

Is indeed the exact same dictionary as

```yaml
the:
  jump: over
  red: fox
```

But since here you are making a list of what should be a dictionary, that's where your issue reside.

---

A little note on the hyphen (`-`), too, because this seems to bug you:

If you prefer it, write your lists like this:

```
- 
  foo: bar
  bar: foo
- 
  baz: qux
  qux: baz
```

This is stricly equivalent to:

```
- foo: bar
  bar: foo

- baz: qux
  qux: baz
```

This would help you see that the hyphen just does delimit the fact that a new element of the list begins there, now you can "condense" it and have a key of your dictionary on the same line as the "new item of list" delimiter (`-`), but you are not forced to.

---

Maybe for an object oriented programming language parallel, if that could be of any help for you, you should think

- a dictionary is like an object, it has multiple properties, but all the properties are actually defining the same object
- a list is a collection of things, it can be a list of object, of integer, or even of object.

So when the documentation says *list / elements=dictionary* they actually want you do construct a list (or collection) where all the elements would be dictionaries (or objects).

---

Maybe the layout on the [documentation page itself](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/cisco/ios/ios_ospfv2_module.html#parameter-config) is easier to read than the table on GitHub.
But there, you can clearly see that the `config` dictionary holds a `processes` list that, itself contains a lot of different dictionaries, among which `address_family`, `adjacency`, ..., `areas`, `network`, ...

[image: parameters table in ios_ospfv2 module]

Comment: Thank you β.εηοιτ.βε.  However what confuses me here is that neither "areas" or "network" are purely dictionaries.  They (like "processes") are of type "list / elements=dictionary".  And considering they are both at the same level (under processes) and both of the same type...why is it that a hyphen before "areas" is acceptable but NOT acceptable before "network"? It's almost as though the documentation is stating that "network" is a "list / elements=dictionary" when in reality it is purely a dictionary. So are we looking at a documentation bug here?

Comment: Because they are supposed to be list under one of the items of the list processes

Comment: Pay attention to how Ansible is also giving you hints here: `areas` is pluralized for a good reason, because it is a list of `area`. Same goes for `processes`. While network is a singular, so, as expected it will be a dictionary and not a list.

Comment: @KeithBogart I added a little note on the hyphen in there, that might answer the misconception you are facing here

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your insights.  I've conferred with others and I think this is an issue of a documentation error for this module. The item of "network" is documented as being "list / elements=dictionary".

In reality the underlying Python code expects to see it as a dictionary (not a list).  When added as a dictionary it works fine. Please see my link in which I provide a screenshot of the (incorrect) documentation as well as the Python error that results when "network" is configured as a "list / elements=dictionary".
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sUSk.png)

Answer (score 0):

Update: I was previously using the Ansible cisco.ios collection version 1.1.0 (which requires that the "network" parameter be entered as a dictionary in the python code for the module, "ios_ospfv2").

**Upon upgrading to version 1.2.0 of the cisco.ios collection** the "network" parameter no longer worked as a dictionary and needed to be changed back to a list (which matches the documentation for this module).

So apparently the version of the Ansible Collection one uses may change how parameters are defined within modules. Moral of the story?  Ensure you're using the latest version of whatever Collection you need.
[Determining Most Recent Collection Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Wquh.png)